# SpringBootTest Property Placeholders Not Resolved

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, properties-file

I have a properties file with two values defined as follows:

```
company.service.host=https://myserver.mycompany.com/services
company.services.clients=${company.service.host}/clients
```

When used within my Spring Boot application, the property substitution works as expected when used within a class called `ClientServiceUriBuilder`. However, when I set up a test class like this (imports omitted for brevity):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ClientServiceUriBuilder.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class TestTest {

  @Autowired()
  ClientServiceUriBuilder uut;

  @Test()
  public void shouldGetClientUrl() {
    String url = uut.getClientGetUrl(12345);
    System.out.println(url);
  }
}
```

The resulting url should be:

```
https://myserver.mycompany.com/services/clients/12345
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
${service.host}/clients/12345
```

The portion of the placeholder prior to the first "." is stripped, and the rest of the unresolved placeholder is returned.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the Spring Boot testing suite?

Comment: Are you using junit 4 or 5? Just to make sure.

Comment: I'm using junit 4.12 and Spring-boot* 2.1.3.

Comment: Just to be sure, there isn't a `source/test/resources/application.properties` file present in which the `${service.host}` SPEL expression is used?

Have you tried using `@TestPropertySource` instead of `@PropertySource`?

Comment: There is an application.properties file in test/resources, but right now it is an exact duplicate of the production file, so no, there is no "${service.host}" expression defined anywhere. Also, I have tried @TestPropertySource and got the same result.

Comment: Try adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation on top of your test class. As far as you have application.properties available in test\resources I don't see it's necessary to define location, thus you can remove `@PropertySource`